Is transcendental number to non zero algebraic power always a transcendental?
My motivation to this question is that we know $e^{a}$ is transcendental , where $a$ is Non-Zero-Algebraic, using Lindemann Theorem, but is it true for all transcendental numbers not only $e$?

Definitely not. For example, let $a$ be any algebraic number not equal to $0$ or $1$. The Gelfond–Schneider theorem tells us that $b=a^{\sqrt 2}$ is transcendental. However, then $b^{\sqrt2}$ is a transcendental number raised to an algebraic power, but $b^{\sqrt2} = (a^{\sqrt2})^{\sqrt2}=a^2$ is algebraic.

First: thank you for your nice answer.

Second: Are you the nice mathematician who introduced the absolutely abnormal number? First time I read about this highly nice number was at beginning of 2022 at wikipedia page about normal numbers.

I didn't initiate the idea of absolutely abnormal numbers, but yes, I'm the author of that 2001 paper that used that phrase and talked about a specific such number  :)  https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/index.shtml?abstract=AAN
